# Unusual Swift Idiom - what does it achieve?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, idioms

I'm working my way through a book on Swift Design Patterns and have come across an example where the author wants to ensure that anyone initializing a subclass of particular class must pass in a value required by the base class:

```
class Employee {
    private var professionBV: String // BV = backingVariable

    private init(profession: String) {
        self.professionBV = profession
    }

    final var profession: String {
        return professionBV
    }
}

// Even if you create your own init here, you always have to pass in a
// value for profession
class Nurse: Employee { }
```

What I don't understand is what the author gaining by using the backing variable in conjunction with the computed property. Isn't it just equivalent to this:

```
// Remove the backing variable, mark profession as final - what have I lost?
class Employee {
    final private var profession: String

    private init(profession: String) {
        self.profession = profession
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re correct - if there’s no setter and no extra processing logic you gain little from this “backing variable” approach.  It’s just clutter.  If later you do find you want to put some logic between the class user and the actual stored variable, you can always switch it to a computed property then (or add a `willSet`/`didSet`).  In fact if the value is immutable after initializing, it should be declared with `let` not `var`.  This mostly sounds like advice from a Java or C# programmer applying practices for those languages to Swift.

Out of interest, what book is this?

Comment: The book is *Pro Design Patterns  in Swift* and I'm actually very impressed with it. It's interesting that you mention ``Java`` and ``C#`` though because the author himself mentions those two languages not far away at all from where he uses this idiom.

Answer (score 2):

The first example makes the profession variable available for reading everywhere - only write access (via the backing variable) is restricted to the same file the Employee class is defined. The second example prevents it also from being read from other files.

But by now there is a better possibility to achieve this - you can configure a different access modifier for the setter:

```
class Employee {
     private(set) final var profession : String
}
```

This leaves the getter with the default permissions but requires the same file for the setter.